# Groups and Private File Visibiility

Tags: 8, files, paragraphs, group

I have created a content type Agenda - the body is paragraphs - there are two types: (1) Text and public files and (2) Private Files.  The fields work properly - Anonymous cannot see Private Files.  Authenticated Users can see Private files.

My issue occurs when I create group content for Agenda.  Non-members can see Private Files.  I cannot figure out where to go to turn this off.  The paragraph Private Files is set for view for authenticated user.  I cannot find in group how to change paragraph.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to implement [hook_file_download()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21File%21file.api.php/function/hook_file_download/8.6.x).